# How to overcome a 422 error on GitHub while creating a repo with my android phone?

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, request, xmlhttprequest

I deleted an old repository after that i tried creating a new one that's when the error started showing,I'm using my phone though and I've been using it for long time to delete and create repository i don't know what change today

I asked chat gpt for help read something related to rate limiting time so i waiting for some hours tried it again and it still didn't work I'm thinking of creating a new github account

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting in a new repo name? It could be possible that your old repo has not been fully deleted on their end yet. If you open your network inspector in your browser, it will give you more details about the 422 error (though this may not be possible on mobile).

Also kudos for doing development on your phone, I wish that there were more tools for doing development on phones since everyone seems to have one nowadays.

Comment: So basically there's nothing else i can other than create another account?